# PowerShell ForEach -parallel file in use

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a simple workflow with a parallel loop but i run into an error  when writing out the result. Because the write-output is parallel. I get the error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is my script:

```
workflow Get-ServerServices 
{
    $srvlst = Get-Content C:\TEMP\srvlst.txt

    foreach -parallel ($srv in $srvlst)
    {
         Get-Service -PSComputerName $srv | Out-File c:\temp\test.txt -Append

    }

}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest writing out to temporary files. You could do something like the below code:

```
workflow Get-ServerServices 
{
    #Get the temp path of the context user
    $TempPath = Join-Path -Path $([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) -ChildPath "ServerServices"
    New-Item -Path $TempPath -ItemType Directory # and create a new sub directory
    $srvlst = Get-Content C:\TEMP\srvlst.txt

    foreach -parallel ($srv in $srvlst)
    {
        $TempFileName = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().Guid + ".txt" #GUID.txt will ensure randomness
        $FullTempFilePath = Join-Path -Path $TempPath -ChildPath $TempFileName
        Get-Service -PSComputerName $srv | Out-File -Path $FullTempFilePath -Force #Write out to the random file
    }

    $TempFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $TempPath
    foreach ($TempFile in $TempFiles) {
        Get-Content -Path $TempFile.FullName | Out-File C:\temp.txt -Append #concatenate all the files
    }

    Remove-Item -Path $TempPath -Force -Recurse #clean up
}
```

Basically you are getting the temp dir, appending a new directory, adding a bunch of GUID named text files with your output, concatenating them all into one, and then removing all of them

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a simpler form by using a buffer and outputting buffer contents at the end:

```
workflow Get-ServerServices 
{
    $srvlst = Get-Content C:\TEMP\srvlst.txt
    $out = @()

    foreach -parallel ($srv in $srvlst)
    {
         $WORKFLOW:out += (Get-Service -ComputerName $srv)

    }

    Out-File c:\temp\test.txt -InputObject $out

}
```

see [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/jj574187.aspx) "Variables in Parallel and Sequence Statements" for more info

Answer (score 0):

Create the test.txt file name based on a variable - then you will have no conflicts.

At the end of the process gather up all the individual files and create one file with all the results - then remove the individual files as part of the cleanup'

Answer (score 0):

As of Powershell 6, Workflow with Foreach-object is no longer used, also the parameter pass has been changed, follow an example below, see if it helps.

```
# Default directory variable
$DefaultDir = "C:\temp\sample"

# Log file.
$LogFile = "$($DefaultDir)\Log\Log_$([DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")).txt"

# Directory where all computers are listed.
$AllComputerFolder = "$($DefaultDir)\ListToCheck\pcs.txt"

# Scan the file that lists all machines to be scanned.
Get-Content $AllComputerFolder | ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
    
    # It will only scan for machines that are connected to the network.
    $TurnedOn = Test-Connection -BufferSize 8 -Count 1 -ComputerName $($_ -replace "\\", "") -Quiet

    # Will scan only for machines that are connected
    IF($TurnedOn -eq $True){

        # Run your script, notice the new way of passing parameters within Foreach-object: $using:DefaultDir
        $Return = ."$using:DefaultDir\Script\script.ps1" $_        
        
        # Writes in file the return of the processing of each machine.
        Add-Content -Path "$using:LogFile" -Value $Return 
    }ELSE{
        # Writes the return of machines with error to file
        Add-Content -Path "$using:LogFile" -Value "$($_) : $([DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")) : Machine turned-off or out of the network"  
    }  

# Number of simultaneous threads
} -ThrottleLimit 20
```