# Powershell writing to text file which is open

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-3.0

I am writing powershell script to read file names from C drive and write to text file. I am trying to log start time and end time before and after logging data. I see the issue that

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Logs.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Is there any option to write to open text files.

```
function log($string)
{
$logfile = "C:/Logs.txt"

   write-host $string 
   $string | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
}


workflow testflow{
Param ($folderPath)
 $Files = Get-ChildItem $folderPath  
 log 'starting'
    ForEach -Parallel($file in $Files)
    {
      try{
         log $file.FullName          
       }
     Catch{
       log 'error occured'
     }
    }
 log 'end'
}
```

Comment: Don't write to the same file inside `foreach -parallel`

Comment: if there is a try catch in foreach -parallel, what would be the best option to log exception to text file?

Comment: Any option to concatenate error message inside foreach parallel and log it?

Comment: Related (with a suggestion to write in temp files first in your parallel foreach, then concatenate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797961/powershell-foreach-parallel-file-in-use